# Can cosmetic method that doesn't involve drugs be patented?

Tags: medicine, health

Just as an example, imagine I found that specific scalp massage technique prevents baldness and have done a study that proves it scientifically, can this be patented?

Comment: Bad example (sorry). Therapeutic methods are problematic, however what you're describing could be a cosmetic method too. Are you interested in those?

Comment: Yes, are the patent regulations different for cosmetic methods?

Comment: Yes, because medical treatments can be excempt from patentability, for example in Europe, while cosmetic methods are not, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Therapeutic methods are patentable as long as there is no prior art disclosure of such  method and has supported scientific data.

Therapeutic methods are patentable only in few jurisdictions, US patent system allow therapeutic method claims but Indian and Swiss jurisdictions don't allow please check does your jurisdiction allows such patents.

Comment: Thanks! Could you attach links of where I can read more about this, e.g. US patent regulation documents.

Comment: @medvedev1088 Please refer to the link below it gives an understanding of subject matter eligibility https://www.uspto.gov/patent/laws-and-regulations/examination-policy/subject-matter-eligibility